# Angular 2 custom select control with dynamic options

Tags: angular, custom-component

I'm trying to implement a custom "myselect control" that describe a "widget object" made by a value and a options array.
This object can change dinamically based on websocket events that produce new objects of the same type and so the "myselect control" should show new options and the new value each time. 
Myselect can also emit an event that returns the object itself with new selected value.

In the plnkr you can see how the options and the value changes if you press the "change widget" button.

Now restart the plnkr , select value "two" first and then press the "change widget" button.

The result is that the options changes but the "myselect control" do not show the new value.
Can someone help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule,Input,Output,EventEmitter,OnChanges,SimpleChange} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {FormsModule}   from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector:'my-select',
    template:`              
        <select *ngIf="widget"
                (ngModelChange)="onChangeValue($event)"             
                [ngModel]="widget.value">
              <option  [ngValue]="item.value" *ngFor="let item of widget.options">{{item.str}}</option>                     
        </select>`
})
export class MySelect implements  OnChanges{
    @Input() widget:Widget=null;    
    @Output() valueChanged:EventEmitter<Widget> = new EventEmitter<Widget>();

    onChangeValue(value) {  
        console.log('WidgetSelect - onChangeValue -> Value:',value);
        this.widget.value=value;
      this.valueChanged.emit(this.widget);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {  
        for (let propName in changes) {
            if (propName=="widget"){                    
                console.log("WidgetSelect - ngOnChanges -> WidgetName :", this.widget,changes["widget"].previousValue,changes["widget"].currentValue);
             break;
            }                       
        }       
    }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `{{title}}<br>
  <my-select [widget]="mywidget" (valueChanged)="printWidget($event)"></my-select>
  <br><button (click)="changeWidget()">Change widget</button>
  `

})
export class App {
  title = "custom select";
  mywidget={
          value:1,
      options:[
        {str:"one",
         value:1},
        {str:"two",
          value:2
        }
      ]

  }
  changeWidget(){
    // set new widget
    this.mywidget={
        value:2,
      options:[
        {str:"one",
         value:1},
        {str:"two",
          value:2
        },
         {str:"three",
          value:3
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  printWidget(widget){
    console.log("widget ---->",widget);
  }

}



@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App,MySelect ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FEPqUuRZwekgFOinPeCi?p=preview)

**EDIT:**

Trying to find the problem that prevents me to fill myselect dynamically (and set default value) , I've create another simple plunker that uses only the string  native type.

[plnkr 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmH8loqbtRo7k5E9wQmr?p=preview)

Comment: What values does `widget.options` contain?. If they are objects the selected property `widget.value` needs to be set to the same object **instance**. Another object with the same properties and values is not be considered the same.

Comment: In the second plnrk, I use only string native type ( i think :D ) ...but the problem is more or less the same. Thanks for your time.